# Replace data attribute value by javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to change `ID="value"` with another id value from tag and I also want to change the value where this name used as target attribute value if there in code

```js
$('div[id]').each(function() {
  $(this).attr("id", "newValueWithRandomNumber")
  // I can change only ID value 

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example1"> I can easily change ID name here </div>


<div id="example2"> I have to find dynamically where this ID used as target value </div>
<div data-bs-target="example2"> button </div>
<div data-*any="example2"> button </div>
<div *any="example2"> button </div>
```

Comment: I don't understand, except that you set the id of the divs to the same value, then what is the problem?

Comment: ID is created dynamically and I want to change it dynamically  in another scenario @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: What scenario ?

Comment: Dynamically creating html block based on  html code that receives from backend so  I want to avoid multiple same ID @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: As far as I know you cannot select elements based on purely an attribute value. You must also know the name of the attribute as well.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes you are right ,  that is the problem I am facing , I am looking for a solution for that

Comment: @evolutionxbox *As far as I know you cannot select elements based on purely an attribute value.* <-- Of course you can: `.querySelector("[attributeName='attributeValue']")`

Comment: You CAN select elements by attribute  name and value combined.

Comment: `data-*any` this is not a great name for an attribute perhaps

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to your question, but your question is an example of why you should avoid using `id`s in the first place - - they create brittle code (as you are now faced with) that doesn't scale well (as you are struggling with). The best solution is to refactor the code to not rely on `id`s in the first place, which is pretty easy as you can: structure the HTML into a reliable patter so that location based selectors can be used, apply classes so that elements can be identified that way, or use attributes. **In your case classes would be an easy solution.**

Comment: Its coming dynamically so I dont  know what is the attributeName @MarkSchultheiss

Comment: @ScottMarcus what you are saying is true in theory, sure - but stuff like `data-bs-target="example2"` suggests libraries like Bootstrap might be in use, which often rely on the use of IDs to connect trigger elements with their respective targets (Bootstrap collapsible/accordion, tabs, etc.) So that might need a lot more rewriting, or even replacing of whole libraries, than a simple "use classes instead" suggests.

Comment: Guess you will have to loop over all descendant elements then, and loop over the attributes of each, checking if the value is an exact match for your div ID. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement doesn't mention it, but all element appear to have a NameNodeMap `attributes`, at least according to my check in Chrome and Firefox.)

Comment: The alternative, dare I even say it, could be to make an exception to the rule "you don't mess about with HTML using Regex!!!1" for once. You know the exact attribute value you are looking for, so writing a regular expression for `any-arbitrary-attribute-name="value"` that should not do any serious damage (unless `any-arbitrary-attribute-name="value"` could also appear in element _content_), could perhaps be an option here.

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ___with your real sample data___

Comment: @ScottMarcus sure, but that example requires you to know `attributeName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this but it is not super fast so you want to limit the scope (not document or body for instance). Two examples but same functional result.
NOTE: Here I dealt with the potentially harder example of data attributes but a  similar process could be done for other attributes.

Second example I added some CSS to show the NOT targeted attribute did not change value;

I put a LOT of comments and console logs in the first example:

```js
function toCamelCase(str) {
  return str.replace(/-([a-z])/g, (x, up) => up.toUpperCase());
}

function datasetNameToCamelCase(str) {
  const dSplit = str.split('data-')[1];
  console.log('split:', dSplit);
  return toCamelCase(dSplit);
}

let newNumber = 0;
let params = [newNumber];
let updatedID = "";
$('#example2')
  .each(function(index) {
    let aNumber = params[0];
    const $el = $(this);
    console.log(this);
    let myId = $el.attr("id");
    $el.prop("id", myId + aNumber);
    let newID = this.id + "-" + aNumber;
    this.id = newID;
    console.log("id three ways newID:", newID, this.id, $el.prop("id"));
    /* filter for elements with Limited scope for speed */
    let $targets = $('body')
      .find('.search-scope')
      .find("*").filter(function() {
        let tgt = this;
        // match JUST the data-* attributes value of the id
        let attrs = [].filter.call(tgt.attributes, at => /^data-/.test(at.name)).filter((t) => t.value == myId);
        return !!attrs.length;
      });
    const hasTargets = !!$targets.length;
    console.log("Targets:", hasTargets, $targets.length);
    $targets.each(function(index) {
      let tg = this;
      let attrb = [].filter.call(tg.attributes, at => /^data-/.test(at.name)).filter((t) => t.value == myId);
      //console.log("data el:",attrb.length);
      attrb.forEach(function(dataAttribute) {
        let cased = datasetNameToCamelCase(dataAttribute["name"]);
        console.log("cased:", cased);
        /* we know we are working with data- so we can use the
         jQuery .data();  
         or the dataset 
         or the .attr() OR the dataAttribute["name"]
         or just the value as dataAttribute.value
        */
        console.log('dataAttribute:',
          "\r\n\tlocalName:", dataAttribute.localName,
          "\r\n\tname:", dataAttribute["name"],
          "\r\n\tattr():", $(tg).attr(dataAttribute["name"]),
          "\r\n\tvalue:", dataAttribute.value);
        const attrThing = $(tg).attr(dataAttribute["name"]);
        const dataThing = $(tg).data(cased);
        const dataSet = tg.dataset[cased];
        console.log("TargetDataset:", attrThing, dataThing, dataSet);
        dataAttribute.value = newID;
        updatedID = newID;
        $(tg).addClass("target");
      });
    });
    aNumber++;
    if (!hasTargets) {
      console.log("No targets found any:", hasTargets);
    }
    // show we just changed the passed one:
    console.log("next:", aNumber, newNumber);
    $('#' + updatedID).addClass("target-source");
  }, params);
```

```css
.target-source {
  border: solid 1px #00ff00;
}

.target {
  border: double 4px #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search-scope">
  <div id="example1">I can easily change ID name here</div>
  <div id="example2">I have to find dynamically where this ID used as target value</div>
  <div data-bs-target="example2">button bs</div>
  <div data-my-fun-any="example2">button my-fun</div>
  <div data-any-giraffe-any="example2">button giraffe</div>
  <div data-any-giraffe-any="example2notme">button giraffe no</div>
  <div my-fun-any="example2">button fun </div>
  <div cheese-any="example2">button cheese</div>
</div>
```

Less noise, but same thing functionally.

```js
function toCamelCase(str) {
  return str.replace(/-([a-z])/g, (x, up) => up.toUpperCase());
}

function datasetNameToCamelCase(str) {
  const dSplit = str.split('data-')[1];
  return toCamelCase(dSplit);
}

let newNumber = 0;
let params = [newNumber];

$('#example2')
  .each(function(index) {
    let aNumber = params[0];
    const $el = $(this);
    const myId = $el.attr("id");
    $el.prop("id", myId + aNumber)
      .addClass("target-source");
    const newID = this.id + "-" + aNumber;
    this.id = newID;
    let $targets = $('body')
      .find('.search-scope')
      .find("*").filter(function() {
        let attrs = [].filter.call(this.attributes, at => /^data-/.test(at.name)).filter((t) => t.value == myId);
        return !!attrs.length;
      });
    $targets.each(function(index, tg) {
      [].filter.call(tg.attributes, at => /^data-/.test(at.name))
        .filter((t) => t.value == myId)
        .forEach(function(dataAttribute) {
          let cased = datasetNameToCamelCase(dataAttribute["name"]);
          dataAttribute.value = newID;
          $(tg).addClass("target");
        });
    });
    aNumber++;
  }, params);
```

```css
.target-source {
  border: solid 1px #00ff00;
}

.target {
  border: double 4px #00ff00;
}

[data-more-noise="freedom"] {
  background-color: #00ff0020;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search-scope">
  <div id="example1">I can easily change ID name here</div>
  <div id="example2">I have to find dynamically where this ID used as target value</div>
  <div data-bs-target="example2">button bs</div>
  <div data-my-fun-any="example2">button my-fun</div>
  <div data-any-giraffe-any="example2">button giraffe</div>
  <div data-any-giraffe-any="example2" data-more-noise="freedom">button giraffe Free</div>
  <div data-any-giraffe-any="example2notme">button giraffe no</div>
  <div my-fun-any="example2">button fun </div>
  <div cheese-any="example2">button cheese</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I really don't like this approach, but if you can't alter the HTML to use classes and make your DOM references that way, you can scan the DOM for the string you wish to replace and replace all occurrences with `.innerHTML`.  This approach could of course be customized to search just parts of the DOM rather than the whole thing.

```js
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replaceAll('="example2"','="example3"');

console.log($("body").html());
```

```html
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example1"> I can easily change ID name here </div>


<div id="example2"> I have to find dynamically where this ID used as target value </div>
<div data-bs-target="example2"> button </div>
<div data-*any="example2"> button </div>
<div *any="example2"> button </div>
</body>
```